# How to handle no response in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added a function in my controller, to provide a way to add record via Get request.

But I don't need to render any page or response to the user.

How to prevent the error exception in Rails console?

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10879ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template
```

My controller

```
  def add_testing_record
    # p request.remote_ip
    # p params
    # ap params.class
    records = params["testing_record"].to_hash.inject({}){|memo,(k,v)| memo[k.to_sym] = v; memo}
    records[:ip] = request.remote_ip
    binding.pry

    TestingCounter.create(records)
    respond_to do |format|

    end

  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `render nothing: true` and `head { 200 }` will remove the error, but they will also cause the browser to display an empty page.

If you want to stay on the same page, you have two alternatives:

1. render the same view at the end of the action.
2. send the request via ajax and return `head`.

On the second, your view should contain something like this:

```
<%= link_to "do_stuff", foobar_path, remote: true %>
```

And, in your controller:

```
def foobar
  # process the request
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {
      flash.now[:success] = "all ok"
      render "the/same/view/template/the/user/is/currently/seeing"
    }
    format.js {
      head 200
    }
  end
end
```

**however**, creating resources on GET is bad. You should really use POST instead:

```
<%= link_to "do_stuff", foobar_path, remote: true, method: :post %>
```

Comment: is there really not a http response designed to say DO_NOTHING

Comment: Not really. Imagine that from the browser's perspective: if no response is returned, it means that the server is not responding (crashed, still working, time out, etc). No response __will__ be interpreted as an error. On the other hand, any of the responses described by me and the other users will send back an _empty_ response, and the browser will use it as appropriate. For HTML requests (the default), the browser expects an HTML response. An empty one will mean "here is the new page to display. It's empty, but please display it anyway". That's why you can use Ajax to avoid this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to render page

then you can use

```
  respond_to do |format|
      render nothing: true
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

i prefer using

```
head :ok
```

This way it will return a response only with headers.

Answer (score 1):

head is more preferred in later rails version

```
head :ok, :content_type => 'text/html'
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-head-to-build-header-only-responses